# Creating a spiral, with gaps and returning to last point of the spiral

Tags: java, algorithm

So I have asked on spigotmc, a minecraft forum and didn't receive much information from it. Basically, I am wanting to create a skyblock code where in essence it spawns a block every 100 blocks away, so it looks something like this:

```
|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|
|X|O|X|O|X|O|X|O|X|O|
|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|
|X|O|X|O|X|O|X|O|X|O|
|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|
|X|O|X|O|X|O|X|O|X|O|
|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|
```

O being an island, X being blank space/air

Having the ability to add another 'island' from where the spiral is essential so it doesn't create one where someone else's is already. I would assume this would be saved as co-ordinates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can construct a simple spiral path out of "L" shapes.

Choose a center point, the size of the gap between the lines, and how big the final spiral is to be.

```
Start in the center.
Set L := size of gap + 1
Set N := L
While N < final size
    Go forward N steps dropping blocks as you go
    Turn left 90 degrees
    Go forward N steps dropping blocks as you go
    Turn left 90 degrees
    Increase N by L
```

Creating a round spiral is harder: [Algorithm to solve the points of a evenly-distributed / even-gaps spiral?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4349375/algorithm-to-solve-the-points-of-a-evenly-distributed-even-gaps-spiral?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

You could always use the modulus operator. That, something like:

```
BlockPos pos = ... //whatever the position is
if (pos.getX() % 100 == 0 && pos.getY() % 100 == 0 && pos.getZ() % 100 == 0){
   // create a block
}
```

The modulus operator, `%`, is the remainder when you divide.

Comment: Yes, but I don't just want a straight line of them.

Comment: Then why'd you ask how to create a straight line of them and draw ascii art of how to create a straight line of them...?

Comment: I didn't, I know the drawing thing is awful and I clearly said "spiral" in the subject and throughout.

Comment: if by "throughout" you mean in one location in the last paragraph then yes, you said it "throughout". I saw a picture that suggested a square grid and the phrase "every 100 blocks"