# Draw fractals lines

Tags: actionscript-3

I found how to make [parabola](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-math-and-actionscript-of-curves-drawing-quadratic-and-cubic-curves--active-11512) and [spiral](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4349375/algorithm-to-solve-the-points-of-a-evenly-distributed-even-gaps-spiral), but don't know how combine both of them and draw random fractal lines.

It is possible to draw with as3 fractal lines like in picture. Not all of them together like tree, but one by one? Any help will be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: This? http://delimiter.ru/games/25-lines/055-25-lines.html

Comment: something little different. Here is my quick example http://cestaslunce.cz/testy/updates/fractal-lines.swf

Comment: finally found one nice example :) http://wa.zozuar.org/code.php?c=9os2